# Using Swig sending list of string from C functions to TCL procs

Tags: c, list, return, tcl, swig

I need guidance on sending a list of string from a C function into a TCL calling function. I am able to send list of integer, float values from C functions back to TCL procedure with the help of swig along with function return value. But I am not able to send a list of strings like “test1”, “test2” from swig back to TCL procs along with return value. Any guidance/pointer to this would be great.

The code that THAT is working is like this

```c
int addsub (int a, int b, int *result1, int *result2) {
  *result1 = a + b;
  *result2 = a - b;
  printf("\n The value is: %i, %i  \n",*result1, *result2);
  return 8;
}
```

Swig interface look like

```c
%apply int *OUTPUT {int *result1, int *result2};
```

TCL Calling is like

```tcl
tclsh
% Addsub 10 5

8 15 5.
```

It give the result output as a list

But when I try to do a similar thing in a string the return list in TCL only return the first character in the string

Code NOT WORKING

```c
int test_str (char *out1, char *out2) {
  char *str1, *str2;
  str1 = "Test1";
  str2 = "Test2";
  strcpy (out1,str1);
  strcpy (out2,str2);
  printf ("Out 1 is %s\n", out1);
  printf ("Out 2 is %s\n", out2);
  return 100;
}
```

Swig interface file look like

```c
%apply int *OUTPUT {char *out1, char *out2};
```

TCL Calling is like

```tcl
Tclsh

% Teststr

Out 1 is est2
Out 2 is Test2
100 101 84
```

It doesn’t give the entire string. Gives the ASCII value of the first letter in the string.

Or if my C function is like this

```c
int test_str (char *out1, char *out2) {
  char *str1,*str2;
  str1 ="Test1";
  str2 = "Test2";
  out1=str1;
  out2=str2;
  //strcpy (out1,str1);
  //strcpy (out2,str2);
  printf ("String 1 is %s\n", str1);
  printf ("String 2 is %s\n", str2);
  printf ("Out 1 is %s\n", out1);
  printf ("Out 2 is %s\n", out2);
  return 100;
}
```

Swig interface file look like

```c
%apply int *OUTPUT {char *out1, char *out2};
```

tclsh

```tcl
% test_str

String 1 is Test1
String 2 is Test2
Out 1 is Test1
Out 2 is Test2
100 0 -127
```

Can someone point out what is missing here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very tricky case. SWIG has particular problems when dealing with `char *` variables used for output; there's simply too much missing information for it to be able to figure out everything it needs to do automatically. (I think it ends up treating them as a length-1 array of characters by default, which isn't very helpful.)

You need to specify an [`argout` typemap](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn32) (and a helper `in` typemap) to fix this:

```
// Allocate a (short) working buffer for the string; this is the part that
// SWIG *cannot* guess for you.
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) char *OUTPUT (char temp[50]) {
    $1 = &temp;
}
// Actually how to do the mapping of strings from a local buffer into Tcl values
%typemap(tcl,argout) char * {
    $result = Tcl_NewStringObj($1, -1);
}
```

You'll then have to `%apply` to actually get the buffer allocation on the correct values. (Be aware that getting buffer management right with this sort of thing is quite tricky, and the function signatures you're working with aren't good candidates for doing a good job of it.)

---

Your last example simply won't work at all; you're not returning the value by any mechanism (due to the way that C strings work; you're just setting things internally to your function, not telling the caller about it). The string isn't *actually* copied unless you do `strcpy`…

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you let me know how to %apply.

Comment: So you suggest to use the strcpy mechanism to do this. But if you see there the first character fo the first variable is missing when TCL prints. When you say it is tricky on this way, is that is any other way of doing this as I need to use this same mechanism multiple times to get strings out from C function and use in my TCL code

Comment: @user I think you're doing the `%apply` right, though I don't really know for sure. The problem is in part `char*` is just pointer-to-`char` (strings are just conventions) and in part that you're very unclear as to what the calling convention in your code actually is. Key questions: What size of buffer? Who allocates the buffer? How does your called code know this stuff? These things are required to get the `%typemap` right…

Comment: I am a beginner in Swig. I am TCL guy. I am trying to send two strings from C functions namely "Test1" & "Test2" to TCL along with a return value which all should be return to TCL as list. My expectation is that from the TCL list got from C, first index of the list to be C return value, second and third elements are the two strings which C function send. I used % apply as it was given in Swig tutorial and it was working for integer returns. I am not sure is that correct approach. I took that approach based on Swig documentation.